# Apply Joomla Template to index.php

Tags: joomla3.0, joomla-template, joomla3.3

I'm new to Joomla, I'm using 3.3.6.  My customer wants a landing page which looks absolutely nothing like the rest of the site.

I asked "[how to create a custom page in Joomla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28257586/creating-custom-joomla-pages)". a while back. The answer was great, and now I have completed a template which looks awesome.  My only problem is, I need to assign this template to index.php not just to some sub page on a menu.  Can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create another menu that won't be visible in the frontend, assign the template there and make it default (in order to be shown as frontpage).